# How to change pivotX, pivotY in android?

Tags: android

I add view dynamically then use `view.setX(100)` and `view.setY(100)`.

I want `setPivotX` and `setPivotY` for use scale animation.

I try `ViewHelper.setPivotX, AnimatorProxy.setPivotX, view.setPivotX` but not working. Some one help me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

Be v a view,

```
v.setPivotX(0);
v.setPivotY(0);
```

Will set the pivot point at (0,0) (left-top)

```
v.setPivotX(v.getWidth() / 2);
v.setPivotY(v.getHeight() / 2);
```

Will set the pivot point at the view center

```
v.setPivotX(v.getWidth());
v.setPivotY(v.getHeight());
```

Will set the pivot point at the bottom right.

After setting the pivot point, you can then rotate the view to see it's working:

```
v.setRotationX((float)45);
v.setRotationY((float)45);
```